# How do I fix hot corners not working in Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: 18.10

I've recently upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 18.10 and hot corners no longer work. It used to work in 18.04. See screenshot below. I have the right bottom corner set to `Show Desktop` but it does not work.

***UPDATE***
This is the GNOME shell extension https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1037/customcorner/?c=45876

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the custom hot corner extension it works here.

Link to the extension: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1362/custom-hot-corners/

Comment: What custom hot corner extension? Could you link it?

Comment: Go here [link] https://extensions.gnome.org/   The easiest way may be to install the gnome shell extention in Firefox.  Good luck  This this the extention [link] https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1362/custom-hot-corners/

Comment: Works like a charm

Comment: Happy it worked for you, enjoy :)

Comment: this extension is not working after u boot

Comment: This one works with a broad variety of gnome-shell versions, including the latest 3.36. The one linked in the question is legacy and works only with older versions of gnome-shell

Comment: @RudolfReal neither extension works after rebooting or logging in/out and has to be manually re-renabled. This seems to be a long-term issue going back many Ubuntu versions.